# How could I create an AVAHI client & server using C++?

Tags: c++, multiplatform, avahi

I'm coding a C++ library that, among other things, needs to:

- Search for a specific service in a network using AVAHI
- Publish itself as a service using AVAHI

I've been searching for existent options. I've found that the creators of POCO C++ offer a [DNS-SD library](http://www.appinf.com/docs/poco/00200-DNSSDTutorialAndUserGuide.html) integrated with POCO C++. That would work, because I'm actually using POCO C++, but it's a commercial library, and I can't afford it.

Apart from that, avahi-daemon offers a client interface that allows [browsing](http://avahi.org/download/doxygen/client-browse-services_8c-example.html) services and [publishing](http://avahi.org/download/doxygen/client-publish-service_8c-example.html) new ones. It also sounds good, but I need my code to be portable, and work in major Linux distributions, Mac OS X and Windows. AFAIK, this solution would only cover Linux (where avahi-daemon is available).

I guess as partial solution, I could just send a properly formatted message via socket and process the raw response. That way, I could search for services published using AVAHI. But I think that's ugly and unmaintainable.

So, is there any good-enough solution for this without buying a software? I know [this can be done using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430245/how-to-develop-an-avahi-client-server), but I need to do it in C++.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You can use the libdns-sd-compat header, you can integrate this easily in C++ with CMake and the hunter package manager which supports avahi as dependency, see an example : https://github.com/ruslo/hunter/blob/master/examples/Avahi/CMakeLists.txt#L16

https://github.com/ruslo/hunter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an Open Source library (released under the [LGPL](http://git.0pointer.net/avahi.git/tree/LICENSE)) available over at http://avahi.org/. It exposes a C interface that can be very easily used in a c++ program.

There are also prebuilt binary version available for all major distros.